# Does Bertrand paradox depend solely on lines in estimating probabilities?

Tags: probability, geometry

Why does Bertrand Paradox depend on lines in estimating probabilities of its different methods?

For example, in method-1, the probability is calculated by comparing the arc of the circle that encloses the equilateral triangle to the remaining arcs which comes up to be 1/3. However, the number of chords that are really enclosed in this area of the circle depends on the proportion of that area of the circle relative to the total area. In that case, method-1 and method-2 will be identical and there would not be any paradox. Method-3 is not well defined for me. But if the principle of calculating the probability based on the surface area rather than the length of lines or arcs is adopted, then that would itself be a progress in solving the paradox.

Comment: There's no need to make progress in "solving the paradox". Most things that are called "paradox" are called that merely because they may seem paradoxical at first sight, not because they actually formally pose a paradox. In the present case, the "paradox" involves three different problems with three different answers and serves as an educational tool underlining the importance of distinguishing clearly between these three problems.

Answer (score 0):

**The Coin Tossing Paradox**

The best way to understand the nature of the Bertrand paradox is to consider an example when intuition guides us well.

Take a coin and toss it. If the probability of getting heads is $\frac 13$ then the probability of getting tails is $\frac 23$. However, if the probability of getting heads is $\frac 12$ then the probability of getting tails is $\frac 12$.

Is it paradoxical that getting tails is $\frac 23$ in the first calculation and it is $\frac 12$ in the second calculation? Obviously not.

In the case of the Bertrand "paradox" the situation is the same: we've been using different models and, as a result, we get different results.

The problem with the human mind is that during the evolution it has not yet been given enough training on guessing chances than, say, on the field of climbing trees. However, if it comes to  angular momentum then the whole world will seem to be quite paradoxical.

Answer (score 0):

But why have we been using different models for a well posed question? While if we use the concept of measuring probabilities based on areas not arcs or lengths, there be only one reduced model which would give an identical result.